# Query timing out because of the number of rows used in a table is too large

Tags: sql, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I have the below query which I am  using to pull out a list of users.

```
select top 10 percent  EMAIL,CUSTOMER_ID,getdate() as date,CUSTOMER_UUID
from Customerd t1

/*exclude*/
where  t1.EMAIL not in (select EmailAddress from [Exclusion_List] )
```

The above query has no errors. The Exclusion_List table has more than 500,000 rows and every month the counts increase by another 500,000.  When I run this query , it times out because of the number of records in this Exclusion_List table.

If I just run the query without the exclusion like below. Then there is no time out issue.

```
 select top 10 percent  EMAIL,CUSTOMER_ID,getdate() as date,CUSTOMER_UUID
 from Customer t1
```

Is there any efficient way to run the 1st query so that I don't get a time out and query runs faster.

Comment: have you tried to use NOT EXISTS ?

Comment: I also used "not in" but did not work. I am not sure how to use joins here for this issue

Comment: select top 10 percent  t1.EMAIL,t1.CUSTOMER_ID,getdate() as date,t1.CUSTOMER_UUID
from Customerd t1 where not exists (select 1 from [Exclusion_List] e where e.EmailAddress =t1.email)    If you may, you can try to create index on EmailAddress  in the table [Exclusion_List]

Comment: You'll need an index on email & emailAddress in each table, presumably customer_Id is the table's clustered key. Bear in mind that a "not in" query will require a scan of the entire index in order to know something is not in it.

Comment: @sergey yes used "select 1" but still the same issue

Comment: LIMIT-ing without ORDER-ing rarely makes sense.

Comment: How many rows does the `Customerd` table have?

Comment: Does the `Exclusion_List` table have an index on `EmailAddress`? For this amount of data this would make a lot of sense.

Comment: Customer table has lot of rows -for example :  5,000,000.

Comment: Exclusion list   table has only "EmailAddress" field

Comment: also tried left join with null value . Still time out

Comment: You'll get a lot more eyes on your SFMC questions over at [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com), specifically with the [marketing-cloud](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud) and [query](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/query) tags.

Comment: Thank you , will add it there